# Jest not creating snapshot or failing tests

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I’m going through a course for React, and after running jest on my first test, it seems like it should be creating my snapshot, but it doesn’t say it has, and I don't see a snapshot file.

When I change the content in the component and run Jest again, it doesn’t fail like I would expect.  I'm just running `jest` from the command line, and it finds the test, but always passes, regardless of how I change the component. (I assume because it's not creating a snapshot to compare against?)

What might I be doing wrong?

Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react'
import Search from './Search'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

test('Search snapshot test', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<Search />)
  const tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `()` at the end:

```
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Comment: FML.  Thanks.  That was it.